# How to use sed and regular expressions to find pattern and remove last few characters?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a gff file in which I need to remove -R* from all lines that have the pattern Parent=gopAga1_........-R.;

The file structure is below shown for a single gene, but I need a global fix for all genes in the file.

```
>2446   17292   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;Name=gopAga1_00004497-RA;Alias=augustus_masked-scaffold4362-processed-gene-0.0-mRNA-1;_AED=0.12;_QI=0|0.8|0.81|1|1|1|11|1368|404;_eAED=0.12;Note=Similar to PLAT: Tissue-type plasminogen activator (Pongo abelii);

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    2446    2545    .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4045;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    6721    6834    .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4046;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    7241    7415    .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4047;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    10114   10205   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4048;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    10478   10649   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4049;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    11037   11122   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4050;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    11518   11713   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4051;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    12794   12930   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4052;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    13006   13146   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4053;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    14920   15047   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4054;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    16051   17292   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4055;Parent=gopAga1_00004497-RA;
```

I am using sed to find patterns but I am unsure how to use sed to remove everything between the last number of the line and semi-colon.

Will my current script work? The expected output is below.

sed 's/Parent=gopAga1_........-R.;$/Parent=gopAga1........;/ gop.gff

```
>2446   17292   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;Name=gopAga1_00004497-RA;Alias=augustus_masked-scaffold4362-processed-gene-0.0-mRNA-1;_AED=0.12;_QI=0|0.8|0.81|1|1|1|11|1368|404;_eAED=0.12;Note=Similar to PLAT: Tissue-type plasminogen activator (Pongo abelii);

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    2446    2545    .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4045;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    6721    6834    .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4046;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    7241    7415    .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4047;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    10114   10205   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4048;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    10478   10649   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4049;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    11037   11122   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4050;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    11518   11713   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4051;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    12794   12930   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4052;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    13006   13146   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4053;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    14920   15047   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4054;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;

>scaffold4362   maker   exon    16051   17292   .   +   .   ID=gopAga1_00004497-RA:exon:4055;Parent=gopAga1_00004497;
```

---

Comment: You should also provide the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
sed 's/-R[^;]*;$/;/'
```

Or

```
awk -F ';' -f OFS=';' '{sub(/-R.*/, "",$(NF-1))}; 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '/^>.*Parent=samp1_/s/-R.;$/;/' <file.fa
>ID=samp1_00004497:4045;Parent=samp1_00004497;
>ID=samp1_00004497:4046;Parent=samp1_00004498;
>ID=samp1_00004497:4047;Parent=samp1_00004499;
>ID=samp1_00004497:4048;Parent=samp1_00004496;
```

The `sed` command above will find all lines starting with `>` and containing the string `Parent=samp1_`, and for each such line replace the final `-R.;` (where the `.` matches a single character) with just `;`.  Lines not ending with anything matching `-R.;` would remain unaltered.

Change the dot in `-R.;` to `[^;]*` if you want to remove any number of non-`;` character up to the `;` at the end.

For your updated question, use `Parent=gopAga1_` in place of `Parent=samp1_`.

Comment: The file is actually a gff3 file. I am updating the question to reflect the full format. This sed command works I specifically need it to also contain Parent=samp1_ as part of the pattern recognition.

Comment: @fargo See updated answer.

Comment: This worked after I removed ^> from the script. I do have a second issue since some lines have multiple parent IDs. For example.
`ID=gopAga1_00004500-RB:exon:4085;Parent=gopAga1_00004500-RB,gopAga1_00004500-RA,gopAga1_00004500;`

I would like to edit the file so that it only reports the first parent ID with everthing after the -RB removed, such as
`ID=gopAga1_00004500-RB:exon:4085;Parent=gopAga1_00004500`

I tried using `sed '.*Parent=gopAga1_/s/-R.*;$/;/'` but was unsuccesful. Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: I realized that my script is editing the very last instance of the pattern. How can I invoke the first instance?

Comment: @fargo There is no reason having `^>` in the expression would have stopped the `sed` script from working, unless your lines does not actually start with `>` as the first character. I don't quite understand what you mean by "report" in your comment. Do you mean you want to delete all but the first parent? If at all possible, your question should be self-contained, and without a string of follow-up questions.  Edit the question and include all relevant information and _exactly_ what you're looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The commandline

```
sed -re 's/([^-]+).+?;/\1;/g'
```

will output everything up to `-` for each line, not including `-` and then append a semicolon to the end.

**Update**

```
sed -re 's/(_.{8})-R./\1/g'
```

will remove unwanted characters based on presence of `_` then 8 chars then `-R`.